# How do I fix a ORA-00902: invalid datatype creating a table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am creating a table in a command SQL sections into a script already populated I have created several tables already but in this one I get a message saying

> ORA-00902: invalid datatype

```
CREATE TABLE Weapons 
(
    id NUMBER(4),
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    damage NUMBER(4),
    company_id VARCHAR2 (10),

    CONSTRAINT pk_Weapons PRIMARY_KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_company 
        FOREIGN_KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_ammo 
        FOREIGN_KEY(ammo_id) REFERENCES Ammo(id)
);
```

Answer (score 2):

In the `CONSTRAINT`, it should be `FOREIGN KEY` and not `FOREIGN_KEY`. Also it should be `PRIMARY KEY`, not `PRIMARY_KEY`.

There is no underscore required as per syntax. So the query will be:

```
CREATE TABLE Weapons (
    id NUMBER(4),
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    damage NUMBER(4),
    company_id VARCHAR2(10),
 CONSTRAINT pk_Weapons PRIMARY KEY(id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_company FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(id),
 CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_ammo FOREIGN KEY(ammo_id) REFERENCES Ammo(id)
    );
```

About Foreign Keys: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/foreign_keys/foreign_keys.php
About Primary Keys: https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/primary_keys.php

Comment: CREATE TABLE Weapons (
    id NUMBER(4),
    name VARCHAR2(30),
    damage NUMBER(4),
    company_id VARCHAR2(10),
    ammo_id VARCHAR2(10),
    CONSTRAINT pk_Weapons PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_company FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(id),
    CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_ammo FOREIGN KEY(ammo_id) REFERENCES ammo(id)
    );
 i have changed the code now but a new error have appear thank you for your answer it was very helpfull aswell as the links u have provided  the error that appeared now is
ORA-02267: column type incompatible with referenced column type

Comment: It may due to the `company_id` in `Weapons` datatype is not same as the `Company(id)` or `ammo_id` in `Weapons` datatype is not same as the `Ammo(id)`. Please match both the column's datatype

Comment: the Create command used in Company Table that posees company id is the following CREATE TABLE Company (
id VARCHAR(3),
 name CHAR(30),
CONSTRAINT pk_Company PRIMARY KEY(id)
);
could it be possible that is due to the lenght of the storage capability inside the id of company?

Comment: @Juan Yes, due to the length of the columns the error occures. So if `company_id VARCHAR2(10)` in `Weapons` table, then in the `Company` table the `id` should be `VARCHAR2(10)` only

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working example. I've created the `AMMO` table (whose description you didn't post, so I used only the `ID` column so that the foreign key constraint wouldn't fail). Pay attention to comments I wrote within the code.

```
SQL> create table ammo
  2    ( id  VARCHAR2(10),
  3      CONSTRAINT pk_ammo PRIMARY KEY(id) );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Company
  2    ( id   VARCHAR(3),
  3      name VARCHAR(30),                   --> switch from CHAR to VARCHAR2
  4      CONSTRAINT pk_Company PRIMARY KEY(id) );

Table created.

SQL> CREATE TABLE Weapons
  2    ( id         NUMBER(4),
  3      name       VARCHAR2(30),
  4      damage     NUMBER(4),
  5      company_id VARCHAR2(3),             --> should match COMPANY.ID datatype
  6      ammo_id    VARCHAR2(10),            --> should match AMMO.ID datatype
  7      CONSTRAINT pk_Weapons PRIMARY KEY(id),
  8      CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_company FOREIGN KEY(company_id) REFERENCES Company(id),
  9      CONSTRAINT fk_Weapons_ammo FOREIGN KEY(ammo_id) REFERENCES ammo(id) );

Table created.

SQL>
```

In referential integrity constraint, you should match datatypes of the foreign and primary key columns. There's no sense in having a `VARCHAR2(10)` in the detail table which points to a `VARCHAR2(3)` column in the master table; you won't be able to put anything longer than 3 characters into the detail table's column anyway (foreign key constraint won't let you).